# exec command in Tcl script excutes silently

Tags: bash, tcl, tclsh

I want to execute following command in tcl script. The command relates to a particular tool.

`exec tool cut Netlists/$::env(DESIGN_NAME).netlist.v`

When the aforementioned command executes on running the tcl script, its corresponding output is not shown on the terminal.

When I try to run this command in tcl shell, it works fine.

Is there any way to print the result on the terminal?

Comment: It works in the Tcl shell because when tclsh operates interactively, it is "helpful" by printing the result of a command it executes. Non-interactive script execution does not produce output unless commanded to do so.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the output to be directed to the terminal, you need to add redirections (otherwise the output becomes the Tcl result of the `exec` command). This is done by appending `>@stdout 2>@stderr` (you usually want to redirect both output and error streams).

```
exec tool cut Netlists/$::env(DESIGN_NAME).netlist.v >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

If you're going to be doing this a lot, it can help to have an assistant procedure:

```
proc tool {args} {
    # You might do other things here, like logging what command was actually called
    exec tool {*}$args >@stdout 2>@stderr
}

tool cut Netlists/$::env(DESIGN_NAME).netlist.v
```

Comment: In simple cases it suffices to do `puts [exec tool cut Netlists/$::env(DESIGN_NAME).netlist.v]`.

Comment: Thanks @Donal Fellows, redirection worked for me.